# Concatenating consecutive strings in an Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to do the following. I have an ArrayList of `String`s and I want to concatenate consecutive elements such that pairs get concatenated and get stred in a new array list. Here is my code

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list3=new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("0100");
list.add("0110");
list.add("0101");
list.add("0101");

for(int in=0,x=0; in<list.size()-1 && x<list.size()/2; in+=2,x++)
{
    list3.add(x, list.get(in)+list.get(in+1));
}   
System.out.println(list3);
```

My question is this won't produce a string which I desire. For instance, I expect 2 strings here each with 8 bits. But this concatenation gives me a string which is longer than 8. Note that this is a dummy values here.In actual,I am reading values from a file and using those values to concatenate. Want guidance on why this code won't work as desired.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you posted works fine. It prints [01000110, 01010101].

Comment: can you paste the output you are getting? While reading from the file there might be additional characters

Comment: It cannot be any other additional characters.Anyway,with my actual file having only 4 bit numbers each in an ArrayList,and after doing this way,I am getting somewhat these: [10101010, 1110011011100110, 1110011011100110, 1110010111100110] etc Note the length

Comment: can you post the file from which you are taking the input.

Comment: Thanks All.I figured it was my own mistake made earlier in the code.But thanks for ur help

Answer (score -3):

Your code is working as per expectation, here. The o/p reproduced by your code `[01000110, 01010101]`.

Comment: But this also an answer.